# Searching a word and displaying its list but now returns null when used Async using Progress Dialog

Tags: android, asynchronous, progressdialog

I have made word search in which searching a word and list related to it is displayed. Data is fetch from url. Its working fine.But when i tried to show PROGRESS Dialog it is not working and list is returning null in OnPost Method.

Below is the link of the code

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn6tm35i9i9gy3y/TabFragment1.java

Another file Searchs the data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p27rpokz68sryv3/SearchData.java

Comment: Please add the code you have used.

Comment: Put some code, this would helpful to solve your problem!!

Comment: With out code we can't help you.You must need to post your code.

Comment: where is the link????

Comment: above is the link please find it...